# Bootstrap 4 not centering vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Something really strange happening, I am using the right classes and style to center my h1 and paragraph. The div with my col-12 that contains the H1 and the other col-12 that contains the paragraph should be close one to another in the center of the Row div.

Why it is not working even tho I am using justify-content center and align-items center? Thank you!

```css
    *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
     background-color: pink;
    }
    
    .red-b{border: 4px solid red;}
    .blue-b{border: 4px solid blue;}
    .yellow-b{border: 4px solid yellow;}
    .green-b{border: 4px solid green;}
    .orange-b{border: 4px solid orange;}
    .black-b{border: 4px solid black;}
    
    /* HEADER */
    
    .main-header{
     background-image: url('header-photo.jpg');
     height: 100vh;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
    }
    
    
    
    .main-header a{
     color: #fff;
    }
    
    .header-banner{
     height: 80vh;
    }
    
    h1{
     color: white;
     font-size: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
                
     h1{
      color: red;
     }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
     h1{
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 70px;
     }
    }
    
    /*MAIN*/
    
    /*FOOTER*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">START BOOTSTRAP</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              
            </div>
          </nav>
    
          <div class="header-banner row justify-content-center align-items-center blue-b">
            
            <div class="col-12 red-b">
              <h1>YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE BOOTSTRAP THEMES</h1>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-12 yellow-b">
              <p class="header-paragraph text-center">lorem ipsum blablabla Montreal Canada</p>
            </div>
    
          </div> <!-- /.row -->
          </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider `align-content-center` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-content)

```css
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body{
     background-color: pink;
    }
    
    .red-b{border: 4px solid red;}
    .blue-b{border: 4px solid blue;}
    .yellow-b{border: 4px solid yellow;}
    .green-b{border: 4px solid green;}
    .orange-b{border: 4px solid orange;}
    .black-b{border: 4px solid black;}
    
    /* HEADER */
    
    .main-header{
     background-image: url('header-photo.jpg');
     height: 100vh;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
    }
    
    
    
    .main-header a{
     color: #fff;
    }
    
    .header-banner{
     height: 80vh;
    }
    
    h1{
     color: white;
     font-size: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
                
     h1{
      color: red;
     }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
     h1{
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 70px;
     }
    }
    
    /*MAIN*/
    
    /*FOOTER*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header class="main-header">
        <div class="container">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">START BOOTSTRAP</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              
            </div>
          </nav>
    
          <div class="header-banner row justify-content-center align-items-center blue-b align-content-center">
            
            <div class="col-12 red-b">
              <h1>YOUR FAVORITE SOURCE OF FREE BOOTSTRAP THEMES</h1>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-12 yellow-b">
              <p class="header-paragraph text-center">lorem ipsum blablabla Montreal Canada</p>
            </div>
    
          </div> <!-- /.row -->
          </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```